# Prevent any disk write in idle

Tags: 16.04, server, hard-drive, smart

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server. And I want to disable hard drive when it is not used for a long time using SMART capabilities.

So, **is it possible to prevent any Ubuntu writes** on a hard drive in idle? And from what things should I start?

Comment: Check out `man hdparm`

Comment: It is not a problem to set hdparm to disable hard drives. The problem is the system always writes something there, so timout never reached. My question is how to **prevent any disk writes**, but not to set up hdparm.

Comment: What is writing to disk? Have a look at [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30286/can-i-configure-my-linux-system-for-more-aggressive-file-system-caching) in terms of more aggressive disk caching. Can the program writing to disk use a RAM disk?

Comment: This is also a [useful answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275678/defer-all-disk-writes-keep-them-in-memory/275846)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a disk to spin down when it is not accessed for a certain period of time

You need to edit /etc/hdparm.conf

try an entry along the lines of

`/dev/disk/by-id/disk_id {
    spindown_time = 36
}`

The spindown time is in blocks of 5 seconds, so 36 means spindown after 3 minutes on inactivity. 
disk_id is the id of the disk you want to spin down (`ls -l /dev/disk/by-id` to find the right one)